# how to compute enthalpy of combustion for methanoic acid

Tags: enthalpy

My [data source](http://www2.ucdsb.on.ca/tiss/stretton/database/organic_thermo.htm) gives the following values for various enthalpies of formation and combustion:

formation of CO2 = -393.5

formation of HCOOH = -425

combustion of HCOOH = -254.3

Wikipedia gives liquid water's enthalpy of formation as -285.

All units are kJ/mol.

I guess the reaction is $4 \mathrm{HCOOH} + \mathrm{O}_2 \to 4\mathrm{CO}_2 + 2\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O}$

LHS enthalpy of formation is $4(-425) = -1700$.

RHS enthalpy of formation is $4(-394) + 2(-285) = -2146$.

So, enthalpy of combusion should be $(1700-2146)/4 = -112$.

**Not** -254!

Can somebody please explain what I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, methanoic acid is usually referred to as formic acid. Although the IUPAC name is methanoic acid, I have never seen anyone call it that (just like water is not referred to as dihydrogen monoxide)

Comment: @ELIJONES Although the systematic name “methanoic acid” is correct, the preferred IUPAC name according to current IUPAC recommendations is still the retained name “formic acid” (see Rule P-65.1.1.1 in the Blue Book).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\ce{4 HCOOH + O2 -> 4 CO2 + 2 H2O}$$

Your reaction equation is wrong. Just count the $\ce{H}$'s on both sides.

The actual equation is

$$\ce{2 CH2O2 + O2 -> 2 CO2 + 2 H2O}$$

which results in the correct enthalpy of combustion.

$$\begin{align}-2\times-393.5\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}-2\times-285.8\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}
+2\times-425.0\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}&=508.6\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}\\
&=2\times254.3\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}\end{align}$$